# Combining json responses of recursive web service calls with PHP and curl

Tags: php, json, api, php5, curl

I'm implementing the [Hotel Price List API](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/HotelsLivePricingList) from Skyscanner. This requires a first call to the service to implement a session followed by 1 or more calls to the service to get the actual results.  I've used curl to implement this and got a working solution, I just wonder if this solution can be improved.

What I have:

```
public static function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
  {
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    // Request json
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json'));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($result, $header_size);

    $APIResult['error'] = curl_error($curl);
    $APIResult['info'] = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $APIResult['header'] = $header;
    $APIResult['body'] = $body;

    curl_close($curl);

    return $APIResult;
}


  public function GetHotels($nodeId) {

    $node = Node::find($nodeId);

    $apiKey = 'prtl6749387986743898559646983194'; // This is the test key

    $currency = $this->request->session()->get('currency');
    $locale = Lang::locale();
    $market = $this->request->session()->get('countryCode');
    $entityid = $node->lat . ',' . $node->lng . '-latlong';
    $checkindate = '2016-12-17';
    $checkoutdate = '2016-12-18';
    $guests = 2;
    $rooms = 1;

    $url = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v3/' . $market . '/'. $currency . '/'. $locale . '/'. $entityid . '/'. $checkindate . '/'. $checkoutdate . '/'. $guests . '/'. $rooms;

    // First call to initiate session, no actual results retrieved
    $APIResult = APIServices::CallAPI('GET', $url, array("apiKey" => $apiKey));


    $debugResult = $APIResult['body'];

    if (!empty($APIResult['info']['redirect_url']) ) {
        $APIResult =  APIServices::CallAPI('GET', $APIResult['info']['redirect_url']);
        $json = json_decode($APIResult['body'],true);

        //Concatenate the json results
        $result = $APIResult['body'];


        while ($json['status'] <> 'COMPLETE') {
            $APIResult =  APIServices::CallAPI('GET', $APIResult['info']['redirect_url']);
            $json = json_decode($APIResult['result'],true);
           //Concatenate the json results
           $result = $result . $APIResult['body'];
        }
    }

  }
```

I know curl is able to automatically follow redirect URL's but I don't know if this would be better?
The current solution to concat the json results in the loop works but is it the proper way to combine multiple JSON results in one?
Any other thoughts, concerns?  This is the first time for me to call a RESTful API.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public static function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
> ```

- Use lowercase first letter for method and function names. `callAPI`.
- Use `null` rather than false as default value for `$data` as this more truly represents what is happening (no value has been passed).
- Once in your method, you are not doing anything to validate that the parameters passed are as expected. For example, `$method` and `$url` should, at a minimum be validated as non-zero length strings.  Perhaps URL also needs to be validated as valid URL and method to be one of set of values you are expecting (i.e. POST,PUT,GET,DELETE,etc.). `$data` should be validated as `null` or non-zero length string. If these validations do not pass, you should fail out of this method (perhaps with `InvalidArgumentException` or similar) and not ever attempt to make a `curl` call.

---

> ```
> $curl = curl_init();
> ```

- Here, you just assume your `curl_init()` works.  You should should check for failure and handle appropriately (log error, throw Exception, etc.).
- Consider moving your curl initialization sequence into its own static method which would initiate and store the curl handle on the class, making it available to the callAPI method.  There is no reason for you to continually set up and tear down curl handles for each API call.  You probably only need to do this once (changing settings on handle as appropriate.
- This centrally stored handle will also be something you will need if you want to be able to optimize your code to making API calls in parallel (more on this below).

---

> ```
> switch ($method)
> {
>     case "POST":
>         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
>
>         if ($data)
>             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
>         break;
>     case "PUT":
>         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
>         break;
>     default:
>         if ($data)
>             $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
> }
> ```

- Rather than having logic here in switch consider actually having distinct `get()`, `post()`, `put()`, `delete()`, etc. methods on your class.  Each method can make necessary config settings on curl handle and then call the central method which makes the API call and assembles the response data structure.

An incomplete implementation for this might be structured as follows:

```
public static function get($url, $data) {
    // make setting changes to curl handle here
    // then call call API method, which at this point is just a 
    // request/repsonse handler
    return self::callAPI($url, $data);
}
```

---

> ```
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
> ```

Consider moving these option settings to common initialization method as noted previously.

---

> ```
> // Request json
> curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
> 'Accept: application/json'));
> ```

Again, probably best set during handle initialization

---

> ```
> $APIResult['error'] = curl_error($curl);
> $APIResult['info'] = curl_getinfo($curl);
> $APIResult['header'] = $header;
> $APIResult['body'] = $body;
> ```

Consider building this as object rather than associative array, as this really seems to be more of a set of object data rather that a hashmap type of data structure.  You might over time also find a need to add behaviors around these properties such that having your own `APIResult` class or similar makes sense.  Passing around an object dependency with known properties and behaviors might be preferable to just passing around a data structure.

---

> ```
> public function GetHotels($nodeId) {
> ```

- Again consider naming `getHotels()` and adding validation for parameter.
- This method doesn't return anything!  What is the point of having this public method if it doesn't do anything for the caller?

---

> ```
> $node = Node::find($nodeId);
> ```

Is `$node` a meaningful variable name here? `$coordinates` perhaps?

---

> ```
> $apiKey = 'prtl6749387986743898559646983194'; // This is the test key
> ```

This should not be defined here in this method.  At a minimum it should be a constant on this class, but would be better still if this was stored in application configuration and not in this code at all.

---

> ```
> $checkindate = '2016-12-17';
> $checkoutdate = '2016-12-18';
> $guests = 2;
> $rooms = 1;
> ```

Why are these hard-coded?

---

> ```
> $url =
> 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v3/'
> . $market . '/'. $currency . '/'. $locale . '/'. $entityid . '/'.
> $checkindate . '/'. $checkoutdate . '/'. $guests . '/'. $rooms;
> ```

Consider having URL base as class constant and having a method to build the full URL

---

> ```
> // First call to initiate session, no actual results retrieved
> $APIResult = APIServices::CallAPI('GET', $url, array("apiKey" => $apiKey));
> ```

If you incorporate other suggestions, this might look like:

```
$APIResult = APIServices::get($url, array("apiKey" => $apiKey));
```

---

> ```
> $debugResult = $APIResult['body'];
> ```

What is purpose of this?

---

> ```
> if (!empty($APIResult['info']['redirect_url']) ) {
>     $APIResult =  APIServices::CallAPI('GET', $APIResult['info']['redirect_url']);
> ```

If you know your API is going to give you redirect, just set curl to follow. Don't write a bunch of nested code to handle these redirects.  What if there are two redirects here?  Your code fails.

---

> ```
>     $json = json_decode($APIResult['body'],true);
> ```

Why would you call this variable `$json` when it does not contain JSON, but rather a data structure resulting from JSON deserialization? Call the variable something that is meaningful to what it is actually storing.
What if `json_decode()` fails (i.e. server sent you something that is improperly formatted)?

---

> ```
>     //Concatenate the json results
>     $result = $APIResult['body'];
> ```

Why are you continuing to work with the raw JSON string here?  You already have a meaningful data structure from the previous line of code.  Concatenating JSON together DOES NOT WORK, as you will get an invalid JSON string.  JSON is ONLY used for data transport, not as a mechanism to build a data structure.  Focus on building an appropriate data structure and then serialize to JSON for delivery.

---

> ```
>     while ($json['status'] <> 'COMPLETE') {
>         $APIResult =  APIServices::CallAPI('GET', $APIResult['info']['redirect_url']);
>         $json = json_decode($APIResult['result'],true);
>        //Concatenate the json results
>        $result = $result . $APIResult['body'];
>     }
> ```

And last but not least.  I think you might strongly consider making these API calls in parallel, as that will be the fastest way for this script to operate (though it would consume more memory as a trade-off).  Take a look at `curl_multi_*` functions (or a library which can better handle your curl operations rather than you coding them manually).  This relates back to earlier point of needing to store curl handle on the class such that each individual call to `callAPI` method (or the wrapper methods).  To implement parallel calls you would likely need to store `curl_multi` handle on the class, with each iteration of this loop adding a new curl handle to the multi-handle and returning data from each API call to be aggregated by calling `getHotels()` method.

I will link you to a lightweight class I had written at one point to manage multi_curl handles geared towards a RESTful use case.  Feel free to use in your application or for inspiration.

https://github.com/mikecbrant/php-rest-client

---

In general, and without seeing your full class implementation, I am worried that your class is doing too much.  Why would one class need to know all of the following?

- How to initiate can configure cURL calls. Ideally this could take a valid cURL wrapper object as a dependency and not have to do anything other than formulating the request and handling the response.
- The low-level details of formulating requests against this specific API (i.e. URL naming, redirection handling, etc.)
- The logic for deriving localization, geography, etc. based on the request/requestor.
- The specifics of performing a hotel search.
- The specifics of getting details for an individual hotel

Comment: you are suggesting to use curl_multi* functions.  If I understand them correctly they will make the calls in parallel.  Knowing that the Skyscanner interface ([link](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/HotelsLivePricingList)) will give me a redirect URL with each poll I do as long as I need to keep polling I'm not quite sure if this is a possible solution.  I don't know all the URL's from the start, I rather get the next URL with each subsequent poll I do.

Comment: @KrisCaluwaerts ok in that case making parallel request might not be a viable approach.

Comment: @KrisCaluwaerts  You might also consider leveraging a queueing mechanism which might allow you to work in parallel as long as you have one authoritative place in memory to access the list of API endpoints that need to be accessed.